# Coppersmith's algorithm like Pari's zncoppersmith?

Tags: polynomials, number-theory, code-request

Is there some Mathematica package (or built-in that I missed) available, more or less equivalent to Pari's [`zncoppersmith`](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html.stable/Arithmetic_functions.html#zncoppersmith) function?

Paraphrasing that source: given a polynomial $P(x)$ with integer coefficients,
`zncoppersmith(P, N, X, {B=N})` uses Coppersmith's algorithm (which in turn uses the [LLL](http://Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz%20lattice%20basis%20reduction%20algorithm) algorithm) to efficiently find all integers $x$ with $|x|\le X$ such that $\gcd(N,P(x))\ge B$. $X$ should be smaller than $\exp\left({\log^2 B\over\deg(P)\log N}\right)$. Parameter $B$ defaults to $N$ if omitted.

Comment: There is nothing built in; not sure about packages. From what I see [here](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/lic13/lec04.pdf) it should not be too hard to implement.